# Observe JSON response if changed from already saved in Database(Realm)

Tags: swift, realm, alamofire, rx-swift

Building an App which is using `Alamofire` and `Realm` for Network call and data storage respectively with help of `RxSwift`. Every thing is working fine but the need of the day is to prevent always refresh views on network call. For now app's behaviour is like I replicate JSON response to DB and then update views from DB. But to always get latest response app needs to call Network API on every `viewWillAppear`. But I don't want to get all DB data and search if there is something changed from new response and then display it. So is there any thing in `Swift` or `Alamofire` or `Realm` that I can observe on if the data is different from previously loaded in database and then only app will update its view.

```
                self?.notificationToken = Database.singleton.fetchStudentsForAttendence(byCLassId: classId).observe { [weak self] change in
                switch change {
                case .initial(let initial):
                    TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "INIT: \(initial)")
                    self!.viewModel.getStudentsData(id: classId)
                case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                    print(modifications)
                    TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "MODIFY: \(modifications)")
                    TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "MODIFY: \(insertions)")
                case .error(let error):
                    TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "ERROR:\(error)")
                }
            }
```

this is how I am observing data now, but As I every time save response into database when I call the API, and I am using `case .initial` to monitor that and as database always have been refreshed and this block calls every time. I need something that monitors that data value changed in DB. Is there something in Realm for that ?

[Link to GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcUFF.gif)

Okay I am doing it like this, there is a viewController in which i have a container view which has Collection view as a child View.

```
private lazy var studentsViewController: AttandenceView = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "attendenceCV") as! AttandenceView
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController, to: studentsView)
    return viewController
}()  //this way I am adding collectionView's container view.
```

here is the ViewModel code from where I am geting my data and creating an observable for CollectionView.

```
class AttendenceVM {

    //MARK: Properties
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let studentCells = BehaviorRelay<[StudentModel]>(value: [])

    var studentCell : Observable<[StudentModel]> {
        return studentCells.asObservable().debug("CELL")
    }

    var notificationToken : NotificationToken? = nil

    deinit {
        notificationToken?.invalidate()
    }
    func getStudentsData(id: Int) {
        let studentsData = (Database.singleton.fetchStudentsForAttendence(byCLassId: id))
        self.notificationToken = studentsData.observe{[weak self] change in
            TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "Switch:::: change")
            switch change {
            case .initial(let initial):
                TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "INIT: \(initial)")
                self!.studentCells.accept(Array(studentsData))
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "MODIF::: \(modifications)")
                self!.studentCells.accept(Array(studentsData))
            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        //self.studentCells.accept(studentsData)
    }
}
```

then I am population collectionView in its class separately, by doing this.

```
class AttandenceView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var studentsView: UICollectionView!

    let studentCells = BehaviorRelay<[StudentModel]>(value: [])
    let scanStudentCells = BehaviorRelay<[ClassStudent]>(value: [])



    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let size = CGSize(width: 105, height: 135)
        flowLayout.itemSize = size
        studentsView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
        studentsView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        setupBinding()
    }

    func setupBinding() {

        studentsView.register(UINib(nibName: "StudentCVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "studentCV")


            //Cell creation
            scanStudentCells.asObservable().debug("Cell Creation").bind(to: studentsView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "studentCV", cellType: StudentCVCell.self)) {
                (row , element, cell) in
                if (element.attandance == 1 ) {
                    // update view accordingly
                } else if (element.attandance == 0) {
                    // update view accordingly
                } else if (element.attandance == 2) {
                     // update view accordingly  

                }
                cell.viewModel2 = element
                }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

            //Item Display
            studentsView.rx
                .willDisplayCell
                .subscribe(onNext: ({ (cell,indexPath) in
                    cell.alpha = 0
                    let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -250, 0, 0)
                    cell.layer.transform = transform
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                        cell.alpha = 1
                        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
                    }, completion: nil)
                })).disposed(by: disposeBag)

            // item selection with model details.
            Observable
                .zip(
                    studentsView
                        .rx
                        .itemSelected,
                    studentsView
                        .rx
                        .modelSelected(StudentModel.self))
                .bind { [weak self] indexPath, model in

                    let cell = self?.studentsView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? StudentCVCell
                    if (model.attandance == 0) {
                       // update view accordingly  

                    } else if (model.attandance == 1) {
                        // update view accordingly  

                    } else if (model.attandance == 2) {
                        // update view accordingly  
                    }

                }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        }
```

**Following is the whole code for Main Viewcontroller**

```
class AttendanceViewController: MainViewController {
    let viewModel: AttendenceVM = AttendenceVM()
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    var students : Results<StudentModel>? = nil
    var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

    private lazy var studentsViewController: AttandenceView = {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "attendenceCV") as! AttandenceView
        self.add(asChildViewController: viewController, to: studentsView)
        return viewController
    }()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if AppFunctions.getAssignedClassId(forKey: "assignedClassId") != 0 { // && pref id isAssigned == true
            let id = AppFunctions.getAssignedClassId(forKey: "assignedClassId")
            self.viewModel.getStudentsData(id: id)
        }

        bindViewModel()

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        classNameLbl.text = "Attandence: Class \(AppFunctions.getAssignedClassName(forKey: "assignedClassName"))"
        students = Database.singleton.fetchStudents(byAttandence: 0, byclassId: AppFunctions.getAssignedClassId(forKey: "assignedClassId"))
        notificationToken = students?.observe {[weak self] change in
            self!.studentAbsentLbl.text = "Students Absent (\(String(describing: self!.students!.count)))"
        }
        if AppFunctions.getAssignedClassId(forKey: "assignedClassId") != 0 { // && pref id isAssigned == true
            let id = AppFunctions.getAssignedClassId(forKey: "assignedClassId")
            getAssignedClassData(classId: id)
        }
    }
    deinit {
        notificationToken?.invalidate()
    }
    func getAssignedClassData(classId: Int) {
        return APIService.singelton
            .getClassById(classId: classId)
            .subscribe({ [weak self] _ in
                TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "\(classId)")
//                self?.notificationToken = Database.singleton.fetchStudentsForAttendence(byCLassId: classId).observe { [weak self] change in
//                    switch change {
//                    case .initial(let initial):
//                        TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "INIT: \(initial)")
//                        //self!.viewModel.getStudentsData(id: classId)
//                    case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
//                        print(modifications)
//                        TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "MODIFY: \(modifications)")
//                        TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "MODIFY: \(insertions)")
//                    case .error(let error):
//                        TestDebug.debugInfo(fileName: "", message: "ERROR:\(error)")
//                    }
//                }
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }

    func bindViewModel() {
        viewModel
            .studentCell
            .asObservable()
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .bind(to: studentsViewController.studentCells)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }
}
```

Comment: Use Realm notifications.

Comment: What change that can bring ? Can you elaborate please

Comment: It's my favorite Realm feature. You set up observers and any time the data changes the views update. There are some great tutorials available.

Comment: Okay great I will try that. Thanks for the information

Comment: Hi need to ask one thing more?

Comment: As I every time save response into database when I call the API, and I am using `case .initial` to monitor that and as database always have been refreshed and this block calls every time. I need something that monitors that data value changed in DB. Is there something in Realm for that ?

Comment: I can do it for a single data in object but I want it for a whole array of Result from DB

Comment: Cross post to [Realm Forums](https://forums.realm.io/t/observe-json-response-if-changed-from-already-saved-in-database-realm/3219/2)

Comment: There's too much code to parse through but there are a few design issues that are contributing to the issue. Remember that Realm objects are live and auto-updating. Your views are fighting that pattern because of this `let studentsData` and the students data is what you want to keep fresh. You should create a class Results var in the view controller to track that data...

Comment: ...So right after this `class AttendenceVM` add a `var studentsData : Results<StudentDataModel>? = nil`. Then in your view did load (or whever) populate that class var, and add a notification to it. As it is, you're polling that student data over and over and that's not necessary - the results will stay fresh continually and the only time you need to update your UI is when there's a change - which is captured by the observer.

Comment: okay if you are saying that I should not do this `let studentsData = (Database.singleton.fetchStudentsForAttendence(byCLassId: id))` in ViewModel class, and make it class variable then how am I supposed to tell the collection view that what data is to populated?. which I think I am doing it here `self!.studentCells.accept(Array(studentsData))` . Or should I move this whole block over there , or what?.

Comment: So this is one problem `Array(studentsData)` - what that's doing is taking studentData, which is a live updating Realm results and 'converting' it to an array which disconnects it from Realm so the objects no longer update. I think this is going to take too much discussion to correct the issue - my suggestion is that make each viewController have a Results class var which is the Realm data  that viewController is responsible for. Attach an observer that that class var so the VC can update the UI when there are changes,.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I will try that surely. Thanks for the time and help. Will let here know you if I need to know something. :)

Comment: there is been an issue while i make `behaviourRelay` with `Results<StudentModel>` like this `    let studentCells = BehaviorRelay<Results<StudentModel>>(value: Results<StudentModel>())` it gives me this error ***Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Results<ClassModel>' with no arguments*** i don't know why it is giving me this. how do I manage to make it go away.

Comment: hey did you got any thing for me? @Jay

Comment: It seems you may have a different question about another set of code, and reading code in comments is tough and on first glance, I don't understand what it's supposed to do. Can you post a different question with the code you're having an issue with? Then we can take a look.

Comment: alright , should i post the other question's link here for you ?

Comment: If you like. Remember to take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way it will have a higher chance of being answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear so this may be totally off base. Let me add a couple of pieces of info that may fit into an answer.

Realm results objects are live updating objects. If, for example, you load in some Dog Objects

```
var dogResults: Results<DogClass>? = nil //define a class var
self.dogResults = realm.objects(Dog.self) //populate the class var
```

and then if you change a dog name somewhere else in your code, the dogResults class var will contain the updated name of that dog.

So, you don’t need to continually refresh that results object as it’s done automatically.

If you want to be notified of those changes, you add an observer to the dogResults class var.

```
self.notificationToken = self.dogResults!.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
```

When you first add an observer, the .initial block is called once and only once. It is not called any time after that. That’s where you would say, refresh your tableView to present the initial data.

When data changes, the .update block is called. You can choose to just reload the tableView again or can make fine-grained changes to your tableView based on the changed data.

Your question states

> But to always get latest response app needs to call Network API on
>   every viewWillAppear.

which isn’t necessary as the class var dogResults always contains updated info.

and along those same lines

> every time save response into database when I call the API

isn’t necessary as the only time you will need to update the UI is from within the .update block.

Lastly, this piece of code seems to be out of place

```
self!.viewModel.getStudentsData(id: classId)
```

however, there’s not enough code in the question to understand why that’s being called in .initial - you may want to consider using the approach presented above instead of polling for updates.

Comment: Okay but one thing I didn’t get from your wonderful answer is that if I have a table view and it has data in it, and i have different cell types for them and, after the api call they all get updated with new data as realm is live. but my view are not shifting as if the data is updated. even after switching tabs and i can see that data is being updated. but i can I notify my views that without reloading them even if I come back from other view controller they did not get changed. how can I deal with that ?

Comment: The tableViews won't get updated unless you specifically call .tableView.reloadData or perform fine grain updates with calls like `tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.`. What does *my view are not shifting* mean.... I am not familiar with *shifting*. Also, what are you asking here *but i can I notify my views that without reloading them*? As far as updating the views - it really depends on how your app is set up. The parent view could tell the child views to reload their tableViews when a Realm .update event is received or they could maintain their own observers.

Comment: i understand what you are saying here and sorry for this if all doesn't sound clear to you, what I am seeking is to only update my views like reload or delete update stuff if the database is being changed from previous data. and I can do that in the observer block as I showed in my code. but my main problem is, when the Network call goes, and I observe using above code it only goes in `Initial` and not in `update`. That is where I want to reload the table only . how can I achive that, If you got my point.

Comment: I have uploaded a GIF for better understanding, in GIF there are two transitions of loading data, one is from DB which is already there, and the other comes over it is after that API call i described above, now I don't want this to be happen like two transitions, only when the data is changed in DB.

Comment: @Ahsan I see what you're doing. However, you edited my answer and the edit should be to your question to make it more complete.

Comment: that was mistake, I fixed it sorry about that. and if you get then help me out please.

Comment: hey @Jay did you have anything for me ?

Comment: @Chalenger I do but there's not enough information in the question to update my answer more fully. Do you have a main view controller with child view controllers? Are the controllers stored in an array? Does each controller have different information? I see from the gif that views slide back and forth but what information is displayed on each view. Can you update your question with more details and perhaps the code you're using to handle the views and also the code that populates your dataSource?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have updated my code block with all the code i am using. see if you can see my problem that i am creating.